# Плагин для вывода ярлычков (наклеек) на миниатюры товаров

Tags: wordpress, плагин, woocommerce, wp-plugin

Кто нибудь встречал такой плагин (WordPress WooCommerce), который позволяет вешать на товары ярлыки (в моём случае будет "в наличии" и "под заказ"), как на картинке: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы выводилась поверх миниатюры картинка. Или может что то похожее встречали, я под себя подверстаю уже как нибудь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть похожий плагин. Называется [**WOO Stickers**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-stickers-by-webline/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Плагин выводит стикеры на карточках товара со следующим текстом:
>   "Новинка", "Распродажа" и "Нет в наличии".

Ключевые особенности:

- Администратор может настроить, сколько по времени товар будет считаться "Новинкой"
- Администратор может настроить внешний вид стикеров
- Администратор может включить/выключить показ стикеров
- Администратор может настроить вывод стикеров как в списке товаров, так и на странице с подробным описанием товара.
- Можно загрузить свой функционал для стикеров